# Error every time I use arrays and matrices c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a program for matrices I get the errors:

error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char str[3][3] = { };
cout <<"Input first row secon row third row"<<endl;
cin >>str[0][0]>>str[0][1]>>str[0][2];
cout <<""<<endl;
cin >>str[1][0]>>str[1][1]>>str[1][2];
cout <<""<<endl;
cin >>str[2][0]>>str[2][1]>>str[2][2];
cout <<""<<endl;
str[3][0]= (str[0][0])[(str[1][1]*str[2][2])-(str[1][2]*str[2][1])];
str[3][1]= (-1)(str[1][0])[(str[0][1]*str[2][2])-(str[0][2]*str[2][1])];
str[3][2]= (str[2][0])[(str[0][1]*str[1][2])-(str[0][2]*str[1][1])];
str[3][3]= (str[3][0])+(str[3][1])+(str[3][2]);
cout <<str[3][3];
std::cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please specify the line number too.

Comment: There is something wrong with the these lines here: str[3][0]= (str[0][0])[(str[1][1]*str[2][2])-(str[1][2]*str[2][1])];
str[3][1]= (-1)(str[1][0])[(str[0][1]*str[2][2])-(str[0][2]*str[2][1])];
str[3][2]= (str[2][0])[(str[0][1]*str[1][2])-(str[0][2]*str[1][1])]; What are you trying to do here? Array is a homogeneous data structure. You do no need to cast here. Please explain.

Comment: You are indexing off the end of the arrays.  `str[3][0]` does not exist.  `char str[3][3]` has legal indices from `[0][0]` through `[2][2]`... i.e. "3" is the array size, but indices are 0, 1 and 2.  Separately, Muhammad has a solid point... what on earth are you trying to do?  Those expressions end up being of the form `(character-value)[(character-value)]`, which is illegal.

Comment: First, if you're using parentheses to group operations, you should use only parentheses. Don't use the `{[()]}` pattern you learned in math class. Second, you have to make multiplications explicit. You can't say `(-1)(str[1][0])`. You have to do `(-1) * (str[1][0])`.

Comment: 1. You cannot omit multiply * 2. Your array is out of bound

Comment: Line 15 character 24 Line 16 character 12 Line 17 character 24 (the parentheses) I'm trying to find the determinant of a 3x3 matrix. I'm also new to c++, I'm self taught.

Comment: So do I make it `int str[3][3] = { };` instead of `char str[3][3] = { };`? What else because like I said I'm new to c++

Comment: I fixed it and I get the wrong answer every time, how can i fix that? and what does it mean to have an array out of bound?

Comment: it means you're trying to access an index that's larger than the number of items the array can hold. you have a 3x3 array but you're trying to access the 4th element which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: There are many errors in this code (both logical and syntax), you should first [learn](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) simple things first.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Illegal indexes. the array that you are using is str[3][0] is out of bound. the maximum array is always one less than the length specified. you can use str[2][0].